# How to insert images in a table's colum?

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

I want to display my testing on some images. And i want to display it in the table. so the table has 3 column.
first : number
2nd: image
3rd:sentence

```
  \begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{Properties} \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    1. & \begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{EPS_Thesis_Farhat/Plat_sukses/B5IB.eps}
     \end{center}
    \end{figure} & sentence\tabularnewline
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
\label{Properties in Regionprops}
    \end{table}
```

How to do it??

Comment: delete `\begin{figure}[!h]\begin{center}` and `\end{center}\end{figure}` You can not use (nor do you want) a figure environment inside a tabular or table environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

- You don't really need a floating object (like `figure`) here. And it's not allowed to nest floating environments.
- By default, if you use `\includegraphics`, the baseline is located at the bottom of the image; to get the desired vertical alignment, I used the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package and its `\adjustbox` command with the `valign=c` option.
- I used the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to have better looking tables; in particular, the use of vertical rules is discouraged (this is, of course, optional).
- The numbering in the first column is automatically produced with the help of a counter.
- If the text in the third column is long, perhaps you'll need a

  ```
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{<length>}
  ```

  column instead of just a `c` column.
- Please do not use `[!h]` as placement specifier for your floating objects; this is so restrictive that it's a recipe for disaster. Use a less restrictive option or, better yet, not option at all.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{myrow}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Properties} 
\label{Properties in Regionprops}
\begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}ccc}
\toprule
& 
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-a}}
& 
sentence \\[1.57cm]
\midrule
& 
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-b}}
& 
sentence \\[1.57cm]
\midrule
& 
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-c}}
& 
sentence \\[1.57cm]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reason, `adjustbox` cannot be used, you can go with `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{myrow}
\newcommand\RaiseImage[2][scale=1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Properties} 
\label{Properties in Regionprops}
\begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}ccc}
\toprule
& 
\RaiseImage[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-a}
& 
sentence \\[1.57cm]
\midrule
& 
\RaiseImage[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-b}
& 
sentence \\[1.57cm]
\midrule
& 
\RaiseImage[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-c}
& 
sentence \\[1.57cm]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment it has been requeste to have the table with the original vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{myrow}
\newcommand\RaiseImage[2][scale=1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Properties} 
\label{Properties in Regionprops}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}c|c|c|}
\hline
& 
\RaiseImage[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-a}
& 
sentence \\
\hline
& 
\RaiseImage[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-b}
& 
sentence \\
\hline
& 
\RaiseImage[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-c}
& 
sentence \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i use winedt. and \usepackage{adjustbox} is not supported. What i have to do?

Comment: @FarhatMann You have two options: 1) use the package manager of your LaTeX distribution to install the package. 2) Use the second approach in my updated answer which doesn't depend on `adjustbox`.

Comment: How to add line at between each column and in the left and the right side. Like an table?
That code doesn't have a line to separate each column in the displayed table.

Comment: @FarhatMann simply use your original format for the `tabular`; see last code in my updated answer.

Comment: I had use the code, but the left side is not has the line..
How about to add the tittle in each column?
i had try this code, but it has errors..


        \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Properties}
        \label{Recognition System's Results}
       \begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}{|c|c|c|}
        No. & Modul & Page's Name \tabularnewline 
        \hline

Comment: @FarhatMann use `\begin{tabular}{|>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Header1}
& Header2
& Header3 
\\hline`

Comment: It's fantastic,, thanx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not interested in getting a legend or whatever, you should first try to remove the `figure` environment. The `center` environment is not needed either, since you already center your table elements (the `c` properties of your tabular). Besides, I am not sure you want (or can) have these kind of environment embedded in your `table` environment

```
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    1. &
    \includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=3.5cm]{EPS_Thesis_Farhat/Plat_sukses/B5IB.eps} & 
    sentence\tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Properties} 
  \label{Properties in Regionprops}
\end{table}
```

Comment: How to make the number and the sentences is locate in center (aligned with the image.) not in bottom of the table?
What i had to do? I have add "[topsep=0pt]", but it doesn't work right.